# How to normalize a url in C?

Tags: c, url

A developer recently wrote a function for me to normalise URLs given a base URL and a URL to normalise. See function below:

```
int
starts_with(const char *str, const char *pre)
{
        size_t lenstr;
        size_t lenpre;

        if (str == NULL || pre == NULL)
                return (-1);

        lenstr = strlen(str);
        lenpre = strlen(pre);

        if (lenstr < lenpre)
                return (-1);

    return (memcmp(pre, str, lenpre));
}

char *
url_sanitize(char *base_url, char *url, int size)
{
        char *newurl;
        int base_url_len = strlen(base_url);

        if (starts_with(url, "http") == 0) {
                newurl = malloc(size+1);
                if (newurl == NULL) {
                        fprintf(stderr, "1 malloc() of %d bytes, failed\n", size);
                        exit(1);
                }

                strncpy(newurl, url, size);
                newurl[size] = '\0';

        } else {
                if (starts_with(url, "//") == 0) {
                        newurl = malloc(size+7);
                        if (newurl == NULL) {
                                fprintf(stderr, "2 malloc() of %d bytes, failed\n", size);
                                exit(1);
                        }

                        strncpy(newurl, "https:", 6);
                        strncpy(newurl+6, url, size);
                        newurl[size+6] = '\0';
                } else {
                        newurl = malloc(base_url_len + size + 2);
                        if (newurl == NULL) {
                                fprintf(stderr, "3 malloc() of %d bytes, failed\n", size);
                                exit(1);
                        }

                        strncpy(newurl, base_url, base_url_len);
                        strncpy(newurl + base_url_len, url, size);
                        newurl[size + base_url_len] = '\0';
                }
        }

        return (newurl);
}
```

The problem is this function doesn't remove `./` or `../`. Also it doesn't lowercase the host and scheme. It doesn't normalise properly. How can the above function be modified to properly normalise a URL?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to talk to the person who developed the code?

Comment: I think you'll need to define normalization in this context, because I don't think there exists a single canonical normalized variant for every given URL, judging from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_normalization. Are you simply after replacing the pathname portion of a URL, that may consist of one or multiple `./` and/or `../`, with a POSIX path of an existing file or folder that contains no `./` and `../`?

Comment: @amn Yes. I definitely want the ./ and ../ removed. Otherwise in my database two or more URLs will match to the exact same resource. From the wikipedia page you referenced I guess the normalisations which preserve semantics is along the lines of what I am after.

Answer (score 0):

The uriparser C library at https://uriparser.github.io/ allows not only parsing a URL but also recomposing, so maybe if you use that library to parse and the recompose you may get the desired result.